# Changing in the relay selection in Tor source code

Tags: relays, circuit, source-code

I want to change the Tor relay selection in the SOURCE CODE, I want to tell Tor to select my selected relays in each time it needs to build a circuit instead of randomly selected relays. 
I know that I can force Tor to select some given relays by modifying Torrc (tor configuration file), but this is not what I want, I need to change the source code, I could not find where in the source code does the relay selection.

Comment: Why do you need to change this in the source code specifically?

Comment: This is a research study.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions for node selection and circuit construction can be found in [`routerlist.c`](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/blob/refs/heads/maint-0.2.4:/src/or/routerlist.c) and [`circuitbuild.c`](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/blob/refs/heads/maint-0.2.4:/src/or/circuitbuild.c) files in `src/or` directory. Possibly the most relevant ones are the following:

- [smartlist_choose_node_by_bandwidth_weights](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/blob/refs/heads/maint-0.2.4:/src/or/routerlist.c#l1964)
- [compute_weighted_bandwidths](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/blob/refs/heads/maint-0.2.4:/src/or/routerlist.c#l1998)
- [circuit_establish_circuit](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/blob/refs/heads/maint-0.2.4:/src/or/circuitbuild.c#l326)
- [onion_extend_cpath](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/blob/refs/heads/maint-0.2.4:/src/or/circuitbuild.c#l3476)
- [onion_pick_cpath_exit](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/blob/refs/heads/maint-0.2.4:/src/or/circuitbuild.c#l3220)
- [choose_good_entry_server](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/blob/refs/heads/maint-0.2.4:/src/or/circuitbuild.c#l3397)
- [choose_good_middle_server](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/blob/refs/heads/maint-0.2.4:/src/or/circuitbuild.c#l3354)
- [choose_good_exit_server](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/blob/refs/heads/maint-0.2.4:/src/or/circuitbuild.c#l3106)

The list may not be exhaustive but should be a good point to start.

In many cases, debug logs can be very helpful for finding responsible code:

> [debug] onion_extend_cpath(): Path is 1 long; we want 3
>   [debug] choose_good_middle_server(): Contemplating intermediate hop: random choice.
>   [debug] compute_weighted_bandwidths(): Generated weighted bandwidths for rule weight as middle node based on weights Wg=0.378600 Wm=1.000000 We=0.000000 Wd=0.088800 with total bw 0
>   [debug] extend_info_from_node(): using 37.59.22.63:9001 for Torlol2
>   [debug] onion_extend_cpath(): Chose router $D12BDD8E7C1C3EDBBDB2FCFF173D8314C8B1E620~Torlol2 at 37.59.22.63 for hop 2 (exit is yahyaoui)